# How can I pass parameters into my put call?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

How can I do a put call where I call an action and then give that action some parameters?

Here is my saga code where I call the action:

```
if (response.data.Success) {
    yield call(DashboardActions.getAnalyticsSuccess(response.data.Object),{dataName: action.dataName});
}
```

Here is the action that has the dataName parameter:

```
export const getAnalyticsSuccess = (state, action, dataName) => {
    const mergedData = {...state.data, ...{ [dataName]: action.data } }
    const newState = state.merge({ fetching: 0, error: null, data: mergedData });
    return newState
}
```

currently, I get this error:

> uncaught at check call: argument [object Object] is not a function

I want to pass dataName into my action so that I can use it to change the correct state as you can see in my action. However, I cannot figure out how to get the dataName value into my action.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

correct yield call:

```
yield put({ type: "GET_ANALYTICS_SUCCESS", data: response.data.Object, dataName: action.dataName });
```